# iis website moved to new directory and connection is disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

i'm new to asp.net & and IIS, i'm developing a website using asp.net for learning. First i create a new blank web site using vwd and the physical directory is C:\inetpub\web1, but later i moved web1 to C:\inetpub\wwwroot and opened IIS and turn the directory to the application and try to run it using browser the error message occur,

```
Server Error in '/web1' Application.

Cannot open database "testdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "testdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.

Source Error: 


Line 34: 
Line 35:         SqlConnection dbCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["testConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
Line 36:         dbCon.Open();
Line 37: 

Source File: c:\inetpub\wwwroot\web1\App_Code\tree.cs    Line: 36 

Stack Trace: 


[SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "test" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool'.]
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject) +1270
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection) +108
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory) +126
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +125
   Node.buildTree(String contentType, String mode) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\web1\App_Code\tree.cs:36
   header.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\web1\header.aspx.cs:14
   System.Web.Util.CalliHelper.EventArgFunctionCaller(IntPtr fp, Object o, Object t, EventArgs e) +14
   System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e) +35
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +91
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +74
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2207
```

Anyone know what is the problem?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The error looks pretty clear to me:

> Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool', at `DbConnectionPool.GetConnection`.

I suppose the site was previously in an application pool that was run by `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE`, and that user was given permissions on the database you want to use, using Integrated Security.

If this is the case, simply change the user your Application Pool runs under.

Comment: "change the user your Application Pool runs under." how to do that?

Comment: @hkinterview seach [IIS change application pool user](http://www.iis.net/learn/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities).